# CSS - child not inheriting the width of a parent in liquid layout

Tags: html, css, width, liquid-layout

All,

This appears to be Firefox related issue (havent tried Opera & IE).

I have 'ul' children which are given a width of 100% in a liquid layout. The parent 'li' itself has a width of 33% of its parent 'ul'.

Chrome seems to display the width of child 'ul' correctly, i.e. its 100% is equal to its parent 'li' width of 33%. However, Firefox stretches the 'ul' child's width to the full viewport width.

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g4VAd/2/

```
            <div id="filemenu">                     <!-- right tabs menu -->
        <ul id="fm_ul">
            <li class="filetabs">File
                <ul>
                    <li class="m_items">Open</li>
                    <li class="m_items">Save</li>
                    <li class="m_items">Exit</li>
                </ul></li><li class="filetabs">Edit
                <ul>
                    <li class="m_items">Undo</li>
                    <li class="m_items">Redo</li>
                </ul></li><li class="filetabs">Settings
                <ul>
                    <li class="m_items" id="frontView"><span>Front View</span></li>
                    <li class="m_items"id="backView"><span>Back View</span></li>
                </ul></li>
        </ul>
    </div>                    <!-- close -> 'filemenu' div -->
```

CSS:

```
    #filemenu {
    float: right;
    width: 37%;
    height: 100%;
}
#fm_ul {
    float: right;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;                 /* Opera & IE9 donot have prefixes, directly support border-radius */
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);                 /* Opera & IE9 donot have prefixes, directly support border-radius */
    background: rgb(232,232,232); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgb(232,232,232) 0%, rgb(252,252,252) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgb(232,232,232)), color-stop(100%,rgb(252,252,252))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(232,232,232) 0%,rgb(252,252,252) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgb(232,232,232) 0%,rgb(252,252,252) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgb(232,232,232) 0%,rgb(252,252,252) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top, rgb(232,232,232) 0%,rgb(252,252,252) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e8e8e8', endColorstr='#fcfcfc',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
}
    .filetabs {
        display: table-cell;
        position: relative;
        width: 33%;
        height: 100%;
        color: rgb(125,125,125);
        font-size: 0.8em;
line-height: 25px;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        -moz-text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(150,150,150,0.4);
        -webkit-text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(150,150,150,0.4);
        text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(150,150,150,0.4);    
        vertical-align: middle;
        list-style-type: none;
    }
        .filetabs:first-child {
            -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 6px;
            -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
            -moz-border-radius-topleft: 6px;
            -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 6px;
            border-top-left-radius: 6px;
            border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;        
        }
        .filetabs:last-child {
            -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 6px;
            -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
            -moz-border-radius-topright: 6px;
            -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 6px;
            border-top-right-radius: 6px;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;        
        }
        .filetabs:hover {
            color: rgb(150,150,150);
            -moz-text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.95);
            -webkit-text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.95);
            text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.95);
        }
        .filetabs ul {
            display: none;
            float: left;
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            opacity: 0;
            -webkit-transition: 0.35s linear opacity;
            -moz-transition: 0.35s linear opacity;
            -o-transition: 0.35s linear opacity;
            transition: 0.35s linear opacity;
            z-index: 100;
        }
            .m_items {
                width: 100%;
                list-style: none;
                padding-top: 1px;
                background-color: rgba(1,1,1,0.8);
                -moz-box-shadow: 2px 0 2px rgba(1,1,1,0.2);
                -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 0 2px rgba(1,1,1,0.2);
                box-shadow: 2px 0 2px rgba(1,1,1,0.2);
            }
                .m_items span {
                    font-size: 0.8em;
                    cursor: default;
                }
                .m_items:first-child {                    /* for borders */
                    -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
                    -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
                    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
                }
                .m_items:last-child {                    /* for borders */
                    padding-bottom: 5px;
                    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
                    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
                    border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
                }
```

Comment: It's not working correctly in Safari either. I'm having a look for the problem now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seem to be with `display: table-cell`. I tried replacing that with `display: inline-block;` and `float: left;` and the submenus started behaving with both.

I would also recommend having a look at this article for vertically centering using `inline-block`: http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown

Comment: Thanks @joshnh. I need the 'table-cell' so that the 'li's text sit in the middle (both vertically & horizontally) in my liquid layout.

Comment: Why not use display: inline-block instead then? It allows for vertical and horizontal centering. I have even written up an article on why you should: http://joshnh.com/2012/02/why-you-should-use-inline-block-when-positioning-elements/

Comment: I cannot vertically align elements with inline-block. Read your article but vertical alignment doesnt work in liquid layout.

Comment: Right, I didn't realise you were working with fluid heights, my apologies. You still should be able to use inline-block though, see here for a solution: http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

Comment: you've brought hope to me, Im playing around with 'padding-top' & 'margin-top' values. CSS-Tricks is talking about table-cell as well...

Comment: It worked! The reader's tip at the bottom of the article, where they create ghost element (or pseudo element), resolved the issue. Thank you for the article ref. joshnh.
Would you please post that as a separate comment or add the reference to the top reply so I can pick the answer as correct.

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad it worked! I have updated my original answer.